# ¿Como crear un GridView en Java Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Mi problema es que trato de poder crear un cuadrilla parecida al **GridView** en **Android** en donde se puedan cargar **JPanel** y estos se posicionen de izquierda a derecha de acuerdo al tamaño horizontal se produzca o no un salto o se genere otra fila. Por ahora estoy usando un **GridLayout** el cual no me da todo lo que quiero por la razón de que este cambia el tamaño de todos los elementos de acuerdo al espacio que este tiene y yo quiero que mantengan el tamaño los **Item**.

**Mi código:**

```
CardLayout card = (CardLayout)jPanel4.getLayout();    
        card.show(jPanel4, "card5"); 

        jPanel31.removeAll();

        cursos = new DF().obtener_cursos();

        if(!cursos.isEmpty()){
                jPanel31.setLayout(new GridLayout(organizar_grid(cursos.size()), 3, 6, 8));

                for(String s : cursos){
                    System.out.println ("--------"+s+"----------");
                    jLabel15.setText(s);
                    jPanel31.add(new new_panel_cur(s));
                }
                jPanel31.updateUI();
        }else{
            jPanel31.updateUI();
            jPanel31.add (jLabel18);
        }
        jPanel30.setSize(jPanel31.getSize().width,jPanel30.getSize().height);
        carg.setVisible(false);
```

Con este código obtengo esto:

[image: Lo obtenido]

Obtengo es que los **Item** o **JPanel** cuyo tamaño es cambiado de acuerdo al espacio que tenga el **GridLayout**.

**Lo que busco**

[image: Lo que busco]

Lo que quiero es que simplemente se carguen los **Item** uno al lado de otro y se mantenga su tamaño y cuando se deba, es decir se sature el espacio horizontal se genere una nueva fila.

Gracias y espero su ayuda.

Comment: Eso se llama flow layout :)

Comment: Pero el flowLayout se controla de esta forma que deseo, no lo habia probado lo voy a intentar.